# How can I store data into map<String, List<String>> using Dart?

Tags: dart

I have the bellow data structure

```
Map<String, List<String>> description = {};
```

And this data:

```
 Key       value
....       .....
 car        bmw
 car        bmw
computer    acer
computer    asus
computer    ibm 
...
```

I want to store data as bellow shows, how can I achieve with Dart

```
 "car"      : ["toyota", "bmw", "honda"]
 "fruit"    : ["apple","banana"]
 "computer" : ["acer","asus","ibm"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that.

```
Map<String, List<String>> description = Map<String, List<String>>();

description['computer'] = ['acer', 'asus', 'ibm'];

description['car'] = List<String>();
description['car'].add('toyota');
description['car'].add('mercedes');
```

If you want to automate, you could do loop. Don't forget to check if the key exist and create it if not.
(Edit thanks to @julemand101)

```
description.putIfAbsent(key, () => List<String>());
```

Comment: You can improve the solution by using the putIfAbsent (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html) method when looking up the map and automatically add a new List instance if there are no instance already.

Comment: Here is what I do and dont work `description.containsKey(key)
          ? description[key].add(value)
          : description.putIfAbsent(key, () => List<String>().add(value));`

Comment: @Dan You are trying to add something during the creation of the List, it doesn't work. What you can do is this ```description.putIfAbsent(key, () => [value]```. Assign a list with values (here just one) to your new key. The ```description['car'].add('toyota');``` works because the list is already created and your are refering to it.